# About Asterisk VOIP

Tags: asterisk

Helo guys ! Can we stop a dns server or starts the dhcp service by using the server asterisk ?? (When the user calls the server he'll receive a response of a part of the server "press button 1 to stop the dns service,2 to restart the server dns".

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that using system comand in dialplan. Or using AGI script.
Please note, asterisk's SIP protocol may not work while no DNS server(new calls).

```
System()  

Execute a system (Linux shell) command Description

System(command) – System command alone System(command arg1 arg2 etc) – Pass in some arguments System(command|args) – Use the standard asterisk syntax to pass in arguments Technical Info

Executes a command by using system(). System() passes the string unaltered to system(3). Running “man 3 system” will show exactly what system(3) does:

system() executes a command specified in string by calling /bin/sh -c string, and returns after the command has been completed.

Therefore System(command arg1 arg2 etc) can be used to pass along arguments. Return codes

System(command): Executes a command by using system(). If the command fails, the console should report a fallthrough. If you need to return a specific value (string) to the dialplan then use either AGI or Asterisk func shell as introduced in Asterisk 1.6.0.

Result of execution is returned in the SYSTEMSTATUS channel variable:

FAILURE Could not execute the specified command SUCCESS Specified command successfully executed APPERROR Triggered for example when you try to delete a file but the file was not there. NOTE – not documented, but can also return APPERROR NOTE – I don’t seem to be able to create a situation when FAILURE will be returned.
```

Comment: Thank you first for the reply! But what I'm trying to ask is that:

when the user calls IVR, the system must propose 5 options which are:
1-restart the DHCP server

2- Restart the DNS server

3-restart the web server

4- Stop the DHCP server

5-Stop the DNS server

you see, so if the user chooses, the system has to execute the command relative the choice

Comment: So what is question? Yes, asterisk can do IVR. No, it can't guess which IVR you need and write it itself. Yes, it can do any system command, may require sudo permission etc etc.

Comment: In fact i don't know how to do it ...

Can you show me what the syntax to write in the ivr for exemple pressing on the button 1 to stop the dns service

Comment: Sorry, no. I can't teach your to write dialplan in one post. Use books like ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony".

Comment: Okay Thank you!!